# Laptop doesn't show up in blueman list of devices (it used to)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm trying to get my headphones to work using Bluetooth under Kubuntu 18.04. for a few brief minutes, they actually did work, but then I accidentally changed something and I haven't been able to get them to work ever since. The fact that they worked briefly is very significant because it demonstrates that the hardware is OK and all the necessary software is installed.

In my struggles with the problem, I inadvertently introduced another problem: the laptop that used to show up in the `blueman` window no longer does, so there's no hope of pairing the laptop with the headphones until I make the laptop visible again.

I don't how I messed up, but the fact that the configuration worked until I perturbed it excludes several causes of the difficulty.  There's nothing wrong with the hardware; all the necessary modules have been installed and are working, and the various configuration files are in good order. I assume that only a small tweak is needed to solve the problem, but I'll be damned if I can find it. There's a major hazard in tweaking the configuration files: I could make the problem much worse.

When the headphones were working they were in the low-fidelity mode, so that's something else that needs to be fixed. But that can come later.

Following the suggestion of pilot6,I'm  providing some more output:

========================================

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue                                      
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[   23.561079] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   23.561116] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   23.561122] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   23.561125] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   23.561130] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.925362] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f36
[   23.925364] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 36
[   39.347022] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   39.347024] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   39.347030] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  149.908763] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  149.908775] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  149.908787] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1275.443468] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[54838.153358] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[54838.153364] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[54838.153366] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[54838.153368] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[54838.163482] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[64916.775086] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000713b37a0 failed to resubmit (2)
[64973.785644] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f36
[64973.785648] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 36
[64973.841857] Bluetooth: hci0: hardware error 0x0c
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command. And also output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: The output is unreadable. Please format it properly. Paste it again, select the text and click the `{}` icon.

Comment: There are errors in `dmesg`. It is either a hardware problem, or a kernel bug.